# Vue.js - import external vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

## Situation

I use vue-cli tool to build my project.

In some reason, i need to dynamic import vue component like `` () => import(`/compiled/component/${var}.js`) `` from local, which is generate by system in runtime or generate by [vue-cli-service](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library).

Is it possible?

i have try many times but never work.
dose there import/export interface different?

Comment: Where are these dynamic components being imported? Is it in your router?

Comment: @Phil yes, i would like to dynamic load component by some variable

Comment: and the component isn't from the project self